# Apache Pig Remove group element from bag

Tags: apache-pig

This seems like it should be something simple to do, but I'm not exactly sure how go about it. After I perform a group in Pig, I only want the numeric elements in the bag (i.e. remove the group/key elements) so that I can sum the numeric values.

So, how can I go from this:

```
(Key1, {(Key1, 10})
(Key2, {(Key2, 5), (Key2, 15)})
```

To this:

```
(Key1, {(10})
(Key2, {(5), (15)})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sum the value based on each key then use the below approach

**input.txt**

```
key1,10
key2,5
key2,15
```

**Pigscript:**

```
A = LOAD 'inpput.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS(key:chararray,value:int);
B = GROUP A BY key;
C = FOREACH B GENERATE group,SUM(A.value);
DUMP C;
```

**Output:**

```
(key1,10)
(key2,20)
```

If you want to keep only the values inside the bag then replace the above 'C'  with this one.

```
C = FOREACH B GENERATE group,A.value;
DUMP C;
```

**Output:**

```
(key1,{(10)})
(key2,{(5),(15)})
```